# RestFul Wcf Video Streaming to iPhone Client

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, windows-server-2008, wcf-data-services

Hi I am trying to play video from my restful wcf service on mobile client. It doesn't play the video in mediaPlayer and in the browser when I open the link it, actually start downloading the file.

Here is the c# Code

```
public Stream playVideo(string VideoId)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (response[1] != null)
            {
                string video_path = Constants._VideosDirectory + "\\" + response[1] + "\\" + VideoId + ".MOV";
                if (File.Exists(video_path))
                {
                    FileStream stream = new FileStream(video_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(video_path);
                    context.Response.ClearContent();
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.FullName.Replace(" ", "_"));
                    context.Response.ContentType = ReturnFiletype(fileInfo.Extension.ToLower());
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "video/quicktime";
                    return stream;
                }
}
}
```

Here is the webhttpBinding for this service

```
<bindings>

     <webHttpBinding>
   <binding transferMode="Streamed"
            maxBufferPoolSize="250000000"
            maxBufferSize="5242880"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            openTimeout="05:25:00"
            closeTimeout="00:25:00"
            sendTimeout="00:25:00"
            receiveTimeout="0:25:00"
            name="webBinding"
       /></webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
 <service behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" name="Test.StreamVideo">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
           contract="Test.IStreamVideo" />
      </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing code to this solved my problem :)

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(video_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "video/quicktime";
                    return stream;
```